# C# : Include a Page_Load DataRow in the page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have done research into pulling data from the Database and it works fine, however, I am currently struggling with getting the data to be passed into the `<ul>` element on the page.

My Page_load function looks like this:

```
// Create Objects
    MySqlDataAdapter query;
    MySqlConnection db;
    int i = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create DataSet to store Database Rows
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        // Attempt to connect the Database
        try {

            // Create a new connection to the Database
            db = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString);
            // Open the connection
            db.Open();
            // Create a new Query
            query = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM `test_table`", db);
            // Add Query results to the DataSet
            query.Fill(ds, "AllData");
            // Create a new DataTable to work from
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            // Append the rows to the DataTable
            dt = ds.Tables["AllData"];
            // Select and store needed information inside an DataRow array
            DataRow[] r = dt.Select("usergroup='1'");
            // Return all values
            Response.Write("<ul>");
            while(i != r.Length)
            {
                Response.Write("<li>" + r[i]["Name"] + "</li>");
                i++;
            }
            Response.Write("</ul>");

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // Display connection error
            Response.Write("ERROR: " + ex);
        }
        finally {

            // Close the connection
            db.Close();

        }

    }
```

I want to now get the Reponse.Write to go inside my ul that I've coded on the aspx page which looks like this:

```
    <%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyLearningSite.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        About
    </h2>
    <p>
        Take a look at all the people that chose us:
    </p>
    <ul>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
```

Does anyone know a simple way I can edit my Page_load function so it automatically goes inside the ul instead of putting it before that page loads?

Comment: .... Why on Earth are you using `Response.Write()`?  You *really* don't want to do that.  Put a control on the page and modify the properties of that control.  (Even just the text of a `Literal` control.)

Comment: New to this, will research how to add controls now :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *almost never* a reason to use `Response.Write()`.  Unless you *really **really*** know what you're doing with the response, don't use it.

Instead of trying to write to the page, put some kind of control on the page and modify the properties of that control.

There are countless ways to do this, and this is admittedly kind of a sloppy approach when compared to things like data binding.  *But*, in the current mindset of outputting raw HTML to the page, this is probably the closest analogy to what you have...

If you put something like a `Literal` control on the page:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        About
    </h2>
    <p>
        Take a look at all the people that chose us:
    </p>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="myLiteral" />
</asp:Content>
```

Then you can set the contents of that control from code-behind:

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
output.Append("<ul>");
while(i != r.Length)
{
    output.Append("<li>" + r[i]["Name"] + "</li>");
    i++;
}
output.Append("</ul>");
myLiteral.Text = output.ToString();
```

(Note: It's been a while since I've had to use WebForms, so this is untested code.  It's really meant to demonstrate the *concept*.  Use controls, of which there are a variety which do various things rather well, as placeholders in the page for the content you want to display.)

Comment: I appreciate the explanation more than the code anyway, you hit the nail on the head with it. Very much appreciated, I'll take it all into account.